# Is it possible to use a ThreadPoolExecutor with a QThread? Seems to create dummy thread that doesn't terminate

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

I'm making an application in PyQt5 that runs a variety of long running tasks, such as scraping web pages. In order to avoid crashing the GUI, I've been using QThreads and QObjects

Currently I have a class that inherits QObject and contains a method for scraping the web pages. I move that object on to a QThread, connect a finished signal with a method that quits the thread and then start the thread.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests


class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.init_ui()
        self.test_obj = None
        self.thread = QThread(self)

    def init_ui(self):
        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        thread_button = QPushButton("Start Thread")
        check_button = QPushButton("Check Thread")
        layout.addWidget(thread_button)
        layout.addWidget(check_button)
        thread_button.clicked.connect(self.work)
        check_button.clicked.connect(self.check)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.show()

    def work(self):
        self.test_obj = TestObject()
        self.test_obj.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.test_obj.finished.connect(self.finished)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.test_obj.test)
        self.thread.start()

    def check(self):
        for t in threading.enumerate():
            print(t.name)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def finished(self):
        self.thread.quit()
        self.thread.wait()
        print("Finished")


class TestObject(QObject):

    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestObject, self).__init__()

    def test(self):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.submit(self.get_url)
        self.finished.emit()

    def get_url(self):
        res = requests.get("http://www.google.com/")
        print(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Everything works as expected, I get a:

"Response [200]"
"Finished"

Printed in the console. However when I check the running threads, it shows dummy-1 thread is still running. Every time I run, it creates an additional dummy thread. Eventually I am unable to create any more threads and my application crashes.

Is it possible to use a ThreadPoolExecutor on a QThread like this? If so, is there a correct way to ensure that I don't have these dummy threads still running once I've finished my task?

Comment: Why aren't you using [QThreadPool](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#)?

Comment: In the full version, I'm using https://github.com/ross/requests-futures to make use of the requests session object and the as_completed feature of concorrent.futures, as this helps to speed eveything up. I'm not sure if I would be able to use them with QThreadPool